# Slice an array starting from first nonzero element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with leading zeros, and I want the array from the first  nonzero element.
For example, I have an array

```
x=[0,0,0,0,0,3,2,0,0,4,5]
```

I want to obtain :

```
 x=[3,2,0,0,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) on `non-zeros`  to get the starting non-zero index and then simply slice it -

```
x[(x!=0).argmax():]
```

Sample run -

```
In [71]: x
Out[71]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5])

In [72]: x[(x!=0).argmax():]
Out[72]: array([3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 6):

What you have is a list, not an array. This is a pure-Python solution, though you might consider converting your list into a NumPy array and going with the Divakar's solution for better performance (if and only if you plan on using NumPy for downstream processing)

```
In [1]: from itertools import dropwhile

In [2]: from operator import not_

In [3]: x = [0,0,0,0,0,3,2,0,0,4,5]

In [4]: list(dropwhile(not_, x))
Out[4]: [3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Often when starting with a list it is faster to stay with the list; and using `itertools` gives this a further edge.